# MariaDB 10.3 does not start after Ubuntu 20.04 reboots after changing the data directory to a different drive

Tags: 20.04, mysql, apparmor, mariadb

I'm having an unusual problem. I tried to change the data directory for my MariaDB installation and it does not work after rebooting the computer:

1. I copied the entries from `/var/lib/mysql/` to `/mnt/Data/mysql` via the rsync command and setting the new directory with the `mysql:mysql` owner by `chown -R ...`.
2. I set the entry `datadir=/mnt/Data/mysql` in the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file
3. I edit the file `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias` by appending a line `alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /mnt/Data/mysql/,` to it.
4. Restart both services by `systemctl restart apparmor` and `systemctl restart mariadb` - so far so good.

---

Yet when I reboot the machine, the MariaDB does not load with the `systemctl status mariadb` of:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.25 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-31 15:50:03 EST; 39min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 559 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 598 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 625 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || >
    Process: 695 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 695 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Dec 31 15:50:02 Server systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.25 database server...
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server mysqld[695]: 2020-12-31 15:50:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 695 ...
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server mysqld[695]: 2020-12-31 15:50:03 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/Data/mysql/Ubuntu.lower-test
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server mysqld[695]: [100B blob data]
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server mysqld[695]: 2020-12-31 15:50:03 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 31 15:50:03 Server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.25 database server.
```

A manual command of `sudo systemctl start mariadb` works however - until the next reboot. There is something that I am missing?

- I check `/etc/fstab` for the hard drive to mount on system startup.
- I checked and double checked the syslog but reported nothing except for a test file cannot be created
- I checked the `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, and reports no errors or warnings

Answer (score 0):

Some how, I found my own answer to this problem after posting this question.

It turned out to be the `/etc/fstab` file in terms of mounting the drive.

Previously, I mounted the drive using the Gnome Disks utility and their modifying of the `/etc/fstab` file didn't allow the MariaDB to connect to the to the hard drive.

A manual, direct editing that critical file solved it.

Here's an example of how `fstab` *should* be edited for the drive to hold the databases:

```
...
/dev/sdb1    /mnt/Data   ext4    defaults    0    0
...
```

That's all to it.

Thanks.